# Is there a way to have sync and async version of the same method with shared code in C#?

Tags: c#, async-await

I need to have a method, which includes call to database. This method needs to exists with sync call to database (will be inside SQL Server CLR) and also with async call to database (this will reside in the client app).

In the sample below, I want MyMethodSync and MyMethodAsync to share as much code as possible, ideally I want just 1 method with bool "call as async".

```
public static class MockDbAccess
{
    public static int GetDbResult(int i, string sql = null)
    {
        return i + sql?.Length ?? 0;
    }

    async public static Task<int> GetDbResultAsync(int i, string sql = null)
    {
        await Task.Delay(2);
        return i + sql?.Length ?? 0;
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    const string SQL = "SELECT Value FROM Table1 WHERE UniqueCode = @I";
    // COPY PASTE version:
    public int MyMethodSync(int i)
    {
        var r1 = i + 4;
        var r2 = MockDbAccess.GetDbResult(r1, SQL);
        var r3 = r1 + r2 * 7;
        return r3;
    }
    async public Task<int> MyMethodAsync(int i)
    {
        var r1 = i + 4;
        var r2 = await MockDbAccess.GetDbResultAsync(r1, SQL);
        var r3 = r1 + r2 * 7;
        return r3;
    }

    // SHARED BUSINESS LOGIC attempt:
    int GetR1(int i) => i + 4;
    int GetR3(int r1, int r2) => r1 + r2 * 7;

    public int MyMethodSync_SharedCode(int i)
    {
        var r1 = GetR1(i);
        var r2 = MockDbAccess.GetDbResult(r1, SQL);
        var r3 = GetR3(r1, r2);
        return r3;
    }
    async public Task<int> MyMethodAsync_SharedCode(int i)
    {
        var r1 = GetR1(i);
        var r2 = await MockDbAccess.GetDbResultAsync(r1, SQL);
        var r3 = GetR3(r1, r2);
        return r3;
    }

}
```

Section SHARED BUSINESS LOGIC attempt is as far as I got. Obviously, in my app, get GetR1 and GetR3 methods are much more complex.

EDIT - to clarify:
I need sync version to call GetDbResult() method (imagine it's some ADO.NET call do SQL Server db) and async to await GetDbResultAsync() (this is call to ASP.NET core web service). The result is exactly the same, the difference is just sync vs. async call to DB.

Comment: What about creating a sync method that does the call and create another method that returns a Task which calls this method within a `return Task.Run( () => SyncMethod() )`?

Comment: I think it's better to use two different methods for the synchronous and asynchronous separate part, methodeName for the synchronous method and methodeNameAsync for the asynchronous method.

Comment: Wrapping a sync call as async is easy, but unfortunately it will not give the best performance.

Comment: @sayahimad But what if you have to repeat 95% of all lines. This goes against the DRY principal.

Comment: @Peter you describe the main issue why implementing `async` in an existing project is so hard.

Comment: @PatrickHofman logically yes because the business logic remains the same, you for your code that repeats you can include it in a method and in this way you can reuse your code in a more elegant and more readable way

Comment: @PatrickHofman - no problem with sync and async implementation, my question is how to share as much code as possible in both

Comment: So you are saying, my suggested "SHARED BUSINESS LOGIC attempt" is the best I can do with sharing code between methods with sync and async call to database?

Answer (score 1):

> Ideally I want just 1 method with bool "call as async".

I think this is doable. In the example below it is safe to call the `Result` of the task that is returned with `async: false`, because no awaiting is taking place inside the hybrid method, so the task is running synchronously.

```
private async Task<int> MyMethodHybrid(int i, bool async)
{
    var r1 = i + 4;
    var r2 = async ?
        await MockDbAccess.GetDbResultAsync(r1) :
        MockDbAccess.GetDbResult(r1);
    var r3 = r1 + r2 * 7;
    return r3;
}

public int MyMethod(int i) => MyMethodHybrid(i, false).Result;

public Task<int> MyMethodAsync(int i) => MyMethodHybrid(i, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no perfect solution to this, unfortunately. There are two halfway-decent approaches for now:

1. Your operation is naturally asynchronous (a db call), so only expose an asynchronous API. Optionally use `ConfigureAwait(false)` everywhere so that synchronous consumers can block on your returned task.
2. Use the [boolean argument hack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx).

The boolean argument hack works by having a core method with a `bool` parameter, with the strict semantics that if that parameter indicates the result must be synchronous, then the core method *must* return an already-completed task. This allows calling code to safely block on it:

```
public class MyClass
{
  const string SQL = "SELECT Value FROM Table1 WHERE UniqueCode = @I";
  private async Task<int> MyMethodCore(int i, bool sync)
  {
    var r1 = i + 4;
    var r2 = sync ? MockDbAccess.GetDbResult(r1, SQL) : await MockDbAccess.GetDbResultAsync(r1, SQL);
    var r3 = r1 + r2 * 7;
    return r3;
  }

  public int MyMethodSync(int i) => MyMethodCore(i, sync: true).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
  public Task<int> MyMethodAsync(int i) => MyMethodCore(i, sync: false);
}
```

Comment: That boolean hack is actually the most clever solution I have seen to this problem!

Comment: @StephanMøller: I learned that hack from Stephen Toub. Here's an [updated version](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2022/10/modern-csharp-techniques-3-generic-code-generation.html#:~:text=Replacing%20Constant%20Arguments).

Comment: I can see that even microsoft hosts a page discussing this solution as the best of their proposed hacks: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development

Answer (score -2):

If you want async call:

```
await MockDbAccess.GetDbResultAsync(r1, SQL);
```

If you want sync call:

```
MockDbAccess.GetDbResultAsync(r1, SQL).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Anywhere you have await put this at end:

> .ConfigureAwait(false);

By the way read this [ASP.NET Core SynchronizationContext](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html)

Also read this: [Why you should use ConfigureAwait(false)](https://medium.com/bynder-tech/c-why-you-should-use-configureawait-false-in-your-library-code-d7837dce3d7f)

Comment: `GetResult()` has the same problems as `.Result` . And we don't know what kind of app this is...  ConfigureAwait() may or may not be helpful.

Comment: Read [ConfigureAwait(false)](https://medium.com/bynder-tech/c-why-you-should-use-configureawait-false-in-your-library-code-d7837dce3d7f) Before down voting..

Answer (score -3):

The two methods will have completely different return types (bool vs Task<bool> ) and names (always suffix with Async), so you can't/shouldn't have a single function that serves both purposes.

That being said, if you implement the async version, then the sync version can just call the async one:

```
public Task<bool> MyFuncAsync()
{
   return true;
} 

public bool MyFunc()
{
   return MyFuncAsync().Result;
}
```

Comment: Except that `.Result()` is very susceptible to deadlocking.

Comment: You could flip the logic and use `Task.FromResult(xxx)` instead of `.Result`

Comment: I need sync version to call GetDbResult() method (imagine it's some ADO.NET call do SQL Server db) and async to await GetDbResultAsync() (this is call to ASP.NET core web service).

Comment: By using Task.Result is accessing the property's get accessor blocks the calling thread until the asynchronous operation is complete .